# Solid background on <li> inside .navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

In **Bootstrap 3** it was possible to do this:

[image]

The effect was to apply a solid background colour (orange in this case) on to an `<li>` element inside `.navbar`

An example fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/p1vm4aeo/

The only custom CSS is the orange background, the rest is Bootstrap 3:

```
.orange-bg {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

Markup is as follows:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div id="navbar-collapse-1" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown orange-bg">
                <a href="#">Foo</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Again this is all standard Bootstrap 3 markup, with the addition of `.orange-bg`.

In **Bootstrap 4** this doesn't seem to be achievable because the `<li>` inside `.navbar` doesn't occupy the full height of the navbar. The effect is like this:

[image]

Fiddle for it is here: https://jsfiddle.net/20ehqxsy/

The only difference in the markup is that the Navbar classes are appropriate to Bootstrap 4 instead of 3 (`.navbar-expand-lg` for instance):

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div id="navbar-collapse-1" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown orange-bg">
                <a href="#">Foo</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Is there any way to get the same effect that's possible in Bootstrap 3 when using Bootstrap 4?

Comment: Just adjust the `padding` and `margin`s of the parent `ul` element and the `li` element to get your desired result. And also look into adjusting the `line-height` value

Comment: Please can you post an example as I can't see how to do this? I tried messing with the margin/padding in Dev Tools and it wasn't doing anything.

Comment: Your 2nd fiddle doesn't render as the image shows. Fixing that will make it easier for us to see what goes on.

Comment: @LGSon the image *is* a screenshot of the fiddle!

Comment: And when I run the 2nd fiddle in Chrome and FF, it does _not_ render like that

Comment: It probably depends on the viewport width due to the `-lg` class on `.navbar`. However at the appropriate width I can confirm it renders the same in Chrome and Firefox. That doesn't change the question though.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply `padding:0` to nav as it takes `padding:16px`. Below is the working tested solution

To make your navbar responsive and collapsible you can use `.navbar-expand-xl|lg|md|sm` refer to [Navbar](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_navbar.asp)

```
nav {
  padding: 0px!important;
}

.orange-bg {
  background-color: orange!important;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand navbar-light bg-light navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div id="navbar-collapse-1" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown orange-bg">
          <a href="#">Foo</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: output]

Comment: you should remove the `-lg` prefixes in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.navbar` element has:

```
.navbar {
    ...
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
}
```

So simply set this to 0, and apply the same value to your most element-local element; for ease of illustration I have used `.dropdown` but you can use `.navbar-nav > li`, etc. :

```
.dropdown {
    ...
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
}

.navbar {
    padding: 0;
}
```

This gives the required result.

Please see this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tpv79kyr/

Comment: The issue with this is that if you add other `<li>` elements into the navbar which do *not* use `.orange-bg` then the heights/alignment is out. I appreciate that's a different issue to the question I asked and I should probably have put other `<li>`'s in my example. The use case in BS3 was to have one item with the orange background, and another 4 items that didn't have it.

Comment: I'll start another question because unfortunately this one doesn't actually solve my problem. The issue is more complex once you add in further items

Comment: @Andy I have created a fiddle with multiple menu options. Please review this. I think I have answered the asked question

Answer (score 0):

A standard navigation bar is created with the .navbar class, followed by a responsive collapsing class: **.navbar-expand-xl|lg|md|sm** (stacks the navbar vertically on extra large, large, medium or small screens).

You need to use bootstraps [utility/spacing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) to achieve the desired result.
Also, notice the use of *nav-link* class inside *li*.

This is a considerably cleaner approach, without overriding bootstraps default css.

```css
.orange-bg {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav class="navbar p-0 fixed-top navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div id="navbar-collapse-1" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown orange-bg">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Foo</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```